# Restricting users on Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph Api for Calendars defines requirement
to add permission to app:

Calendars.ReadWrite - Read and write calendars in all mailboxes

see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events

Is there a way to restrict it further on Azure?

For example:
restrict the app to only be able to read calendars from a user john@bestpirnt.com, not a ceo@bestprint.com

I Looked through documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies

It's seems to miss this type of functionality.

Comment: This should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

Comment: that's seems like solution, I will test it, thanks!